# Clone a Post Tite and Custom Field into Custom Post type

Tags: plugins, redirect, wp-redirect, genesis-theme-framework

I am using Simple Urls to setup redirects on my blog. I am trying to create redirects automatically upon publishing a post. For example, If i publish a post about StudioPress it will be automatically publish a redirect with Title similar to blog post. i.e StudioPress. and the "URL" custom field will update the Redirect url in Simple URLs Plugin.

In simple terms, i want to clone blog post for "surl" (CPT name of Simple URLS Plugin) post type  with similar title and for redirect url i will setup a Custom Field Named "URL".

I am somehow successful in cloning the post title but the redirect url is not copying. Here is my code. Please have a look and correct the error for Custom Field URL.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_postdata_wpse_76945', 10, 2 );
function save_postdata_wpse_76945( $post_id, $post_object )
{
// Auto save?
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;

// Correct post_type
if ( 'post' != $post_object->post_type )
    return;

// Security
if (
    !isset($_POST['noncename_wpse_76945'])
    || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['noncename_wpse_76945'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) )
    )
    return;

// Prepare contents
$add_cpt_clone = array(
                'post_title'   => $post_object->post_title,
                '_surl_redirect' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'url' ),
                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                'post_type'    => 'surl'
              );

// Insert the post into the database
$p_id = wp_insert_post( $add_cpt_clone );

// Use $p_id to insert new terms
}
```

I know i am doing some mistake here

```
'_surl_redirect' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'url' ),
```

But i don't know how to correct it. I am using ACF for generating custom field URL.

Any Ideas. It's very urgent and i am using Genesis and therefore, i don't want to use any other plugin that is not done by Genesis team. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work-

```
if( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_surl_post_id', true ) ) {
    // we have an old post created here
    update_post_meta( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_surl_post_id', true ), '_surl_redirect', get_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', true ) );
    return;
}

// Prepare contents
$add_cpt_clone = array(
                'post_title'   => $post_object->post_title,
                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                'post_type'    => 'surl'
              );

// Insert the post into the database
$p_id = wp_insert_post( $add_cpt_clone );

// Insert the meta key for redirect
update_post_meta( $p_id, '_surl_redirect', get_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', true ) );
// save the id for future use
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_surl_post_id', $p_id );

// Insert any other meta keys that might be needed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mridul Aggarwal for solving the prior issue, I am now facing another issue. After Publishing a post when i update the custom field URL, it doesn't get updated in the Simple URLs Plugin. How can i do that as well?

Comment: That should be possible using a `save_post` hook. But you also need to establish a link between the earlier post and the newly created post. You could use `update_post_meta( $post_id, '_surl_post_id', $p_id )` to save the new post's id with the old post's meta. Then create a separate hook on `save_post` action, which will check if the meta was updated and update the other post's meta if it did.

Comment: `save_post` will not handle any programmatically applied updates, so if that's a concern, you might want to look into the hooks available in function `update_metadata()`

Comment: Hi Mridul, I am not that good in PHP and hooks. Can you please update the above code so that i can paste that in my functions file. I will be obliged. Thanks

Comment: Hey, i have updated some untested code, i think it should work. Also note that it will work on newly created posts, not the old ones.

Comment: Mridul, The above code is not working. Can you please recheck once again. Thanks

Comment: I don't exactly see the issue with this code here. Maybe try removing the `return;` inside the if condition. But that will end up creating new clones, each time you update the post, which is likely to cause other problems.

Comment: I tried it again and again and finally got it working by removing the security lines from the below code. However, I found that whenever, I update a post it clones a new entry in the SURL Post type rather than updating the existing entry. Can you please verify one more time, if there are any issues. Thanks

Comment: In my original answer the first if condition checks for the existing entry only. I think adding that if condition back should fix the repeated clones.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you please update the code with if condition.

Comment: It's there in the answer right now. Just copy the first 4 lines from the main answer

Comment: Hi Mridul, I already added those four lines. You can see the code i am using below.

Comment: Mridul, after a lot of research, i think the issue is with the priority. Can you please check the below code and let me know if the priority is ok. It will be a great help for me. Thanks

Comment: I don't think the priority could have issues here unless you have more than one hook acting on the same data.

Comment: If i remove the if security, it will save the redirect but without title as auto draft and even if i just open the post page and do not publish a post.

Comment: Can i give you wordpress access and you can have a look yourself. It will be of great help for me

Comment: I can't really do much here. Maybe you can create a new question, and a fresh set of eyes may be able to point something.

Comment: I have no words to express thanks for your wonderful effort and pointing me to the right direction. Thanks Mridul. I will update here if i found some solution. Regards

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. I somehow found that it may be because of ACF generating the meta box and is working differently than update post meta. What do you say? Is it that issue? If yes, then is this code not compatible or i can make it compatible. Do note that this is the correct order of using the code                                                               `update_field($meta_key, $meta_value, $post_ID);`

Comment: `update_post_meta` should work fine with ACF. ACF generates it's own meta boxes but under the hood they use the same old wordpress API. Shouldn't exactly be a problem.

Comment: Hi Mridul, I found a similar code that is working. Can you please check and find what's wrong with ours. I will be really grateful to you. Posted Below in the answers. No room here.

Comment: I think the issue is with we have to unhook the save post function and hook it again. I didn't try because i don't know where to put  it.

Comment: Hi Mridul, It's only you that made it work. The code is now working and updating the existing custom field. The minor issue of title clone is not working. Thanks

Comment: `get_the_title($post_id);` should give you the post title

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above code. It completely stopped working. Can you please recheck it once if i am pasting the full code correctly. Thanks

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_postdata_wpse_76945', 10, 2 );
function save_postdata_wpse_76945( $post_id, $post_object )
{
// Auto save?
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;

// Correct post_type
if ( 'post' != $post_object->post_type )
    return;

// Security
if (
    !isset($_POST['noncename_wpse_76945'])
    || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['noncename_wpse_76945'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) )
    )
    return;

if( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_surl_post_id', true ) ) {
    // we have an old post created here
    update_post_meta( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_surl_post_id', true ), '_surl_redirect', get_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', true ) );
    return;
}

// Prepare contents
$add_cpt_clone = array(
                'post_title'   => $post_object->post_title,
                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                'post_type'    => 'surl'
              );

// Insert the post into the database
$p_id = wp_insert_post( $add_cpt_clone );

// Insert the meta key for redirect
update_post_meta( $p_id, '_surl_redirect', get_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', true ) );
// save the id for future use
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_surl_post_id', $p_id );

// Insert any other meta keys that might be needed

}
```